# iPhone development- how to authenticate a user through a remote service?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, authentication

I am developing an iPhone application and a website simultaneously. I plan on making an API for the website so that the app can send a URL request to get things done. For example, they send a request to `www.example.com/journal/add/1` and it will add the item with id `1` to their journal.

What I don't know, is how to do I authenticate them through the iPhone application? I would like them to login just once and have it save their "session". Should I just store the username/password in a plist, and then authenticate them every time they make a request (so I would have to send their username and password hash through every request, like `www.example.com/journal/add/1/user/hash`? Seems hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try oauth, or implementing a simple key system, where logged in users get a key to make subsequent requests with, either way you can refer to the facebook, twitter, youtube apis, you can see how they do it, get some ideas from there (they are all pretty similar) though they concentrate on letting external users make the calls, but you can still do something similar...

Comment: So to implement the simple key system, I would just have a table on the server with userID/key fields... when the user logs in on the iPhone, it saves the key on the iPhone and in the database. When the user wants to do something, the iPhone sends something like `example.com/journal/add/1/key`, and the server looks up the key to see which user is assigned to that key?

Comment: yea, when user logs in u assign a random unique key to the user id, and then the subsequent requests contain the key in there...there are aditional security measures such as signatures, etc to avoid various kind of attacks, for example if you send the key user pair in as plain text someone can sniff it out and use the info to make their own requests..

Answer (score 0):

instead of keeping their login and pass you should keep sessionid (make it using time, login and md5 checksum)

so first, do normal authorization with your php script (you will need to use database), if it's successful, return sessionid to iphone client. iphone client stores it locally. then next time user starts app you check if sessionid is there: if yes, you send it to your server for authentication. Server checks if sessionid is in the database - if YES, it returns success to client and updates session id in database (remember that you can sessionids can be time stamped, so user will have to relogin if there was long inactivity)

sounds complicated but it's not that bad ;)

Comment: Okay, so the app would be sending the session ID to the server every time it makes a request? And each request the server would check for the session ID, if it's there get the user ID for that session, and apply whatever action the user requests to that user ID? Sounds like a plan.

Comment: @LoganSerman yes, exactly. you use session id to quickly and easily identify your user without need to re-authenticate